# Rename file name based on folder name

Tags: python

i can't seem to figure out how to create a for loop to rename my files based on my folder name..

eg. 
folder - `2021/Category/Fruits/` 
filename - `2021_Category_Fruits_Apple.jpg`, `2021_Category_Fruits_Orange.jpg` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module:

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path("d:/test") # path to your folder
files = list(folder.rglob("*.jpg")) # get all jpg files from subfolders
for f in files:
    name = "_".join(f.parts[-4:]) # the last four parts of full name
    new_file = Path(f.parent / name)
    f.rename(new_file)
```

Actually an implementation depends on your workflow. Here is a probably a little bit more smart variant of the same code:

```
folder = Path("d:/test")             # path to your folder
folder_parts_len = len(folder.parts) # len(["d", "test"])
files = list(folder.rglob("*.jpg"))  # all jpg files from subfolders

for f in files:
    file_parts = f.parts[folder_parts_len:] # ["2021", "Category", "Fruits", "Apple.jpg"]
    name = "_".join(file_parts)             # "2021_Category_Fruits_Apple.jpg"
    new_file = Path(f.parent / name)
    f.rename(new_file)
```

Comment: ahh finally... thank you so much for ur help Yuri!

Answer (score 0):

Split the pathname on "/", then join on "_".